# Execute Appium test cases via Appcenter task in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: java, azure-devops, appium-android, visual-studio-app-center

How to configure correctly and execute the test cases using Appcenter task in the Azure VSTS pipeline.

In the repository, have two directories {source, testcase} in the parent directory. The build executes in hosted Mac OS triggered by VSTS pipleline.

In the first task, from source directory, create the .apk file and copy to artifacts staging directory.
In the second task, Run the Automated test cases using Appcenter task "Test with Visual Studio App Center".

I am having trouble understanding, how appium works and make it work via VSTS pipeline.

In the first approach, after the .apk buil then would like to execute the test cases using Appcenter and Appium. but it was not successful since one of my test case file has hardcoded values like below.
have one file /src/test/java/company/domain/com/util/android/UtilSetup.java which has hardcoded values like below. because of hard-coded values, it was looking for appium and it throws connection issues. so went on to second approach to make the pipeline work.

```
public class UtilSetupAndroid {
        public static EnhancedAndroidDriver<MobileElement> driverAndroid;
        public static void setupAndroid() throws MalformedURLException {
                DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
                caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, Platform.ANDROID);
                caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
                caps.setCapability("deviceName", "hexa-decimal-value-here");
                caps.setCapability("udid", "same-hexa-decimal-value-here");
                caps.setCapability("appPackage", "cl.company.transformacion.appcompanymobile");
                caps.setCapability("appActivity",
                                "cl.company.transformacion.appcompanymobile.enrolamiento.activity.CargaInicialActivity");
                caps.setCapability("app", "/home/directory/Appium-test/project.apk");
                caps.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
                caps.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
                driverAndroid = Factory.createAndroidDriver(url, caps);
                driverAndroid.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
}
```

In the second approach, did a local build(mvn test) and it has generated the *.class files of test cases. The committed the "test-classes" directory in the test cases build directory and referred in Appium configration secion. Committing the *.class files is not right approach i believe, but to make the pipeline work, did it like this.
Then, build pipeline started executing the Appium but ended with unresolved dependency error. I had the same issue and to overcome the issue, added the company nexus repository to directly download from Nexus. but still error occurs.

```
pom.xml has dependencies like below:
       <dependency>
         <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
         <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
         <version>6.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>com.microsoft.appcenter</groupId>
         <artifactId>appium-test-extension</artifactId>
         <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
build section like below:
  <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>prepare-for-upload</id>
         <build>
            <plugins>

               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.8.0</version>
                  <configuration>
                     <source>1.8</source>
                     <target>1.8</target>
                  </configuration>
               </plugin>

               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
               </plugin>

                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.10</version>
                  <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/upload/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
                           <useRepositoryLayout>true</useRepositoryLayout>
                           <copyPom>true</copyPom>
                           <addParentPoms>true</addParentPoms>
                        </configuration>
                     </execution>
                  </executions>
               </plugin>

               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.2</version>
                  <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <id>generate-pom</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>effective-pom</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                           <output>${project.build.directory}/upload/pom.xml</output>
                        </configuration>
                     </execution>
                  </executions>
               </plugin>

               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                  <executions>
                     <execution>
                        <id>copy-testclasses</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                           <goal>testResources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/upload/test-classes</outputDirectory>
                           <resources>
                              <resource>
                                 <directory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</directory>
                              </resource>
                           </resources>
                        </configuration>
                     </execution>
                  </executions>
               </plugin>

            </plugins>
         </build>

         <reporting>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
               </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </reporting>

         <repositories>
            <repository>
               <id>jcenter</id>
               <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
            </repository>
         </repositories>

      </profile>
   </profiles>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>COMPAY_NAME.cl</id>
        <url>http://maven.COMPANY_NAME.cl/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>    
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>COMPANY_NAME.cl</id>
      <url>http://maven.COMPANY_NAME.cl/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

Error message:

```
Reason: [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building run-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.microsoft.appcenter:appium-test-extension:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.958 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-19T01:45:22+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project run-test: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xamarin.appium:run-test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.microsoft.appcenter:appium-test-extension:jar:1.0 in cache1 (http://cache1:6081/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

[EDIT]
Additional information, my pom.xml does not have the project in "com.xamarin.appium". It seems the error from App Center. Also the maven repo in the output is not my maven repository.

The REST call from appcenter-cli to App Center is returned with status 2xx for first few calls and finally throws the error.

```
[command]/usr/local/bin/appcenter test prepare appium --artifacts-dir /Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/a/AppCenterTest --build-dir /Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/s/Test/test_case --debug --quiet
Using appcenter-cli version: 1.1.18
Preparing tests... done.
Tests are ready to run. Manifest file was written to /Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/a/AppCenterTest/manifest.json
[command]/usr/local/bin/appcenter test run manifest --manifest-path /Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/a/AppCenterTest/manifest.json --app-path /Users/vsts/agent/2.153.2/work/1/a/AppCOMPMobile.apk --app COMPchile/AppAndroid --devices COMPchile/set-pruebas-vsts --test-series pruebas --locale en_US --debug --quiet --token ***
Using appcenter-cli version: 1.1.18
Preparing tests... done.
(truncated)
Response status code: 200
Body: {"message":["Tests completed. Processing data."],"wait_time":10,"exit_code":null}

Current test status: Tests completed. Processing data.
logFilter, request: {
  "rawResponse": false,
  "queryString": {},
  "url": "https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/COMPchile/COMPAppAndroid/test_runs/b8b88f0f-226c-4564-98b5-dc582cca81c8/state",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "user-agent": "appcenterCli/1.1.18 NodeJS/v6.17.0 darwin/18.6.0",
    "x-api-token": ***
  },
  "body": null
}
Response status code: 200
Body: {"message":["Failed!","Reason: [INFO] Scanning for projects...\n[INFO]                                                                         \n[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------\n[INFO] Building run-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT\n[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------\n[WARNING] The POM for com.microsoft.appcenter:appium-test-extension:jar:1.5 is missing, no dependency information available\n[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------\n[INFO] BUILD FAILURE\n[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------\n[INFO] Total time: 2.132 s\n[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-21T19:23:12+02:00\n[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/309M\n[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------\n[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project run-test: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xamarin.appium:run-test:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.microsoft.appcenter:appium-test-extension:jar:1.5 in cache1 (http://cache1:6081/maven2) -\u003e [Help 1]\n[ERROR] \n[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.\n[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.\n[ERROR] \n[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:\n[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException\n"],"wait_time":10,"exit_code":2}
```

Comment: Could you try moving the `jcenter` repo section out of <profile> and up so that it's in the top level <repositories> section?

Comment: You shouldn't need to run the tests within VSTS - having an active App Center account and uploading the tests using the App Center Test task should be enough. If you're still stuck after trying the above (and maybe double checking you've applied everything here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/preparing-for-upload/appium) I would reach out to App Center support in the appcenter.ms portal.

Comment: @OwenNiblock- Still seeing the same error after moving the jcenter out of <profile> and up to top level <repositories> section. In vsts, having tasks to create apk, prepare for upload (-DskipTests -P prepare-for-upload package) and then App Center Test. What you mean by run the tests within VSTS.

Comment: I would reach out to support with a link to the test run, it'll be much easier for us to see what's going on that way :)

Comment: @OwenNiblock - yeah, i have shared the link to Chat support and added to microsoft github account for their attention. thanks for your help.